# survcomp package : could not find function "hazard.ratio"

Tags: r, bioconductor

Does anyone know why this does not run? What I did was:

```
source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("survcomp")
library(survival)
library(prodlim)
```

and then, copy and paste of what this website says for my excise.
https://rdrr.io/bioc/survcomp/man/hazard.ratio.html

```
set.seed(12345)
age <- rnorm(100, 50, 10)
stime <- rexp(100)
(abridgement)
weight <- runif(100, min=0, max=1)
hazard.ratio(x=age, surv.time=stime, surv.event=sevent, weights=weight, strat=strat)
```

Then, I got an error like:

```
Error in hazard.ratio(x = age, surv.time = stime, surv.event = sevent,  : 
  could not find function "hazard.ratio"
```

If I simply wrote and enter like:

```
hazard.ratio
```

Then, it appears:

```
"Error: object 'hazard.ratio' not found"
```

Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe you didn't load the library? `library(survcomp)`

Comment: That's it!

Now I know who is famous.
Now I understand correctly why you have such a great reputation.

Thank you very much for all you have done for me, question edit and so on.
I do appreciate it.